# How do I determine how much power a USB device has negotiated?

Tags: linux, usb, embedded-linux

I know that when a USB device first connects to a computer/hub it can only draw 100mA (150mA if it is USB 3.0).  It must negotiate for higher power via a Configuration Descriptor's `bMaxPower` field.  The host may then select this configuration or select something lesser.

So, for example, a device may request 500mA, but it might only receive 300 (e.g. if there's a hub that can't provide more).

Is there a way (in Linux, preferably) to know the result of this negotiation?  More specifically, if I'm developing an embedded device, I would like to know if I got my entire request or not.  If I can't get enough power for full functionality, I would like to reduce functionality or present an error to the user.

So far (using `lsusb` and the equivalent files under `sysfs`), I've only been able to find the amount requested, not the amount that's been negotiated.

Comment: Could the device itself measure and report how much it _receives?_ With a sufficiently junk cable, what the port provides and what the device receives might not necessarily agree...

Comment: A device can measure what it is currently consuming.  But the only way to measure what a supply is capable of delivering is to add load until you see a voltage drop (or blow a fuse or get cut off by the hub), which isn't really a good idea.  Hence the desire to see the results of the negotiation.

Comment: So the device with Linux where you want to know is a USB peripheral that draws power from some host, not a USB host, right?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Correct.  It is based on an NXP i.MX8 mini MCU.  It is currently self-powered (with batteries) but we want to make it bus-powered, so knowing how much current we are allowed to draw is important.

Answer (score 0):

Negotiated doesn't matter, it's how much power your getting that matters.  Get a USB power meter, with bluetooth and a USB bluetooth dongle will receive the power information over bluetooth to your linux box.

If your drawing more current that the device can provide the voltage will be lower and expected.

Thus you can monitor it in realtime.

Now wireshark has a USB module for intercepting USB commands, but I have no idea if it is compatible with linux.

Comment: It depends on your purpose.  If I want the host to know the device's power-draw, of course, it needs to be measured.  But if the device wants to know how much was negotiated, in order to selectively disable its own features in order to remain within that power budget, then it clearly needs to know what was negotiated.